# i want to make timer to record event as interval time wil change and total time also changeable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, arduino

I am new to Programming, and have an Arduino project, which is sending data continuously which I am recording in vb as chart and datagridview.

It has fixed timer now, but I want to make it user-friendly as if I set total time to 5 minutes and interval of 1 minute, then it will record only 5 records, if total time  is 5 minutes and interval is 30 seconds then it will record 10 records.

How can I set the timer to custom value and the custom time intervals?

Comment: If data is transmitted to your vb  program via Serial, this might be the easiest way to send parameters the other direction as well. But your question is very vague, IMO.

Comment: Dear sir,  My Arduino is Sending Data Continuously, but it will depends on me when ever i want to display or record as per my need after 1 sec, 10 secs, 60 secs, or whatever, secs increment or decrement by buttons

Comment: Of course you can use buttons alternatively, but then you need some feedback to show the current state. If you do not want to modify your VS2010 VB program, better concentrate on Arduino code and the desired Serial output (as seen by  Serial Monitor)